# Procedure insertSerial has no parameters and arguments were supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

Below is my SP stored in MSSQL server.

```
USE [testdb]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[insertSerial]    Script Date: 11/05/2012 16:38:20 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertSerial]
AS

DECLARE @start int
DECLARE @end int
DECLARE @expdate datetime

BEGIN TRAN
WHILE @start < @end
BEGIN
 INSERT tbl_serial VALUES (@start, @expdate)
 SET @start = @start + 1
 END
 COMMIT TRAN
```

and then I try to call the SP from my ASP.NET application like this -

```
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insertSerial", sqlconn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", txtStart.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", txtEnd.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@expdate", System.DateTime.Now);

        try
        {
            sqlconn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            lblStatus.Text = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlconn.Close();
        }
```

Then I got this `Procedure insertSerial has no parameters and arguments were supplied.` error. Is it because the way I declare parameters in SP is incorrect? If so, how do I fix them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sp is invalid sql

This is how to declare params

`ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[foo]
    @bar                INT
AS
BEGIN`

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for the answer. However, I still do not understand how it is done. Could you perhaps show me the example by modifying my code?

Comment: Never mind, I've re-created another SP as your example. Works great now :)

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure don't have parameteres, so you can `declare your parameters` in your stored procedure `between brackets`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.insertSerial
(
    @start  varchar(1024),
    @end varchar(1024),
    @expdate datetime

)
....
```

Comment: But I want to pass the values from the text box.

Comment: yes but you must declare your parameters in your stored procedure, your code c# is good

Answer (score 0):

you are Declared SQL Variable in this SP, you need to define Parameter in this sp 
like

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertSerial]
 @start int
 @end int
 @expdate datetime
AS
```