# SQL error with Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I am inserting rows in sql table through my c# code , which calls a Stored procedure .

C# code:

```
SqlCommand myCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();
                myCommand.CommandText = "FederationUpdateCTRAndImpressionCountsForAllYPIds";
                myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                myCommand.Parameters.Add("@bid", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
                myCommand.Parameters.Add("@uid", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
                myCommand.Parameters.Add("@imp", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                myCommand.Parameters.Add("@ctr", SqlDbType.VarChar);

                while (myfederationReader.Read())
                {                      
                    myCommand.Parameters["@bid"].Value = myfederationReader["BusinessId"];
                    myCommand.Parameters["@uid"].Value = myfederationReader["UId"];
                    myCommand.Parameters["@imp"].Value = myfederationReader["Impression"];
                    myCommand.Parameters["@ctr"].Value = myfederationReader["CTR"];                    
                    rowsAffected = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();                        
                }
```

Stored proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FederationUpdateCTRAndImpressionCountsForAllYPIds]
    @bid uniqueidentifier,
    @uid uniqueidentifier,
    @imp varchar(255),
    @ctr varchar(255)
AS  BEGIN   
    UPDATE  BasicBusinessInformation
    SET     BasicBusinessInformation.CTR = @ctr , BasicBusinessInformation.Impression = @imp
    WHERE   BasicBusinessInformation.BusinessId = @bid AND  BasicBusinessInformation.UId = @uid 
    END
```

On executing it , following error is reported:

> procedure has no parameters and arguments were supplied

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230126/procedure-insertserial-has-no-parameters-and-arguments-were-supplied

Comment: Is `thisConnection` the same connection you are using for the DataReader `myfederationReader`? Is your procedure in the same database as your reader source? If you expand the procedure in Enterprise Manager, does it show parameters there?

Comment: Is there another procedure called `FederationUpdateCTRAndImpressionCountsForAllYPIds` in a different schema with no parameters, more specifically your default schema? What happens if you schema qualify the procedure name in the SqlCommand?

Comment: First make sure about using the dbo schema. myCommand.CommandText = "dbo.FederationUpdateCTRAndImpressionCountsForAllYPIds";

Comment: Are you failing on the `ExecuteNonReader()` shown here, or are you failing earlier, when you try to get `myfederationReader`?

Comment: can d downvoter xplain d downvote ?...what a bunch of stupid people..

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'd say that 'Need help, urgently' doesn't garner upvotes - neither does the fact that you apparently can't be bothered to answer even a single of the relevant elaborating questions that have been asked above, yet have time to write 'what a bunch of stupid people'

Comment: And here comes another one from the bunch !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clearing the Command parametres

```
[C#] 
public bool ExportAndClear() {
SqlParameter[] myParamArray = new SqlParameter[myCmd.Parameters.Count - 1];
myCmd.Parameters.CopyTo(myParamArray, 0);
myCmd.Parameters.Clear();
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to fetch data from reader before you fire this command
like

```
1)Fetch data from reader and store in list or datatable
2)For loop on list or datatable
3)in for loop fire this command
```

Answer (score -3):

Try moving the following

```
SqlCommand myCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();
                myCommand.CommandText = "FederationUpdateCTRAndImpressionCountsForAllYPIds";
                myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                myCommand.Parameters.Add("@bid", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
                myCommand.Parameters.Add("@uid", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
                myCommand.Parameters.Add("@imp", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                myCommand.Parameters.Add("@ctr", SqlDbType.VarChar);
```

In the while loop, see if you get different results.

Comment: I did not change anything. I suggested you to try moving the adding of the parameters within the while loop. By doing that, the command is created each time, and so are the parameters.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you read the comment, I suggested to move the code snippet highlighted, in the while loop.